# Bash grep is not working with apostrophe

Tags: bash, ssh, centos, centos6

I've tried to run this code:

```
lsof | grep "/file/path/"
```

If the file has this sign:

> `

I get an error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token '`'
```

I've tried to escape this sign with `\`, but I got the same error.

Operation System: CentOS 6

Comment: I don't see any part of your code that could cause an unexpected error. You sure that's the only thing you run? Also what do you get if you just run `lsof`?

Comment: What file? You're passing the standard output of one command to the standard input of another.

Comment: If you mean the file you want to grep for has that character in it then escaping it in the argument to grep should work but if it doesn't for some odd reason you could also try using single quotes around the argument instead of double quotes. But please provide **exact** commands that cause the problem.

Comment: what does "If the file has this sign '" mean? it can't be that if ' is part of lsof output, witness   echo "ab'cd" | grep "b"  -- also  echo "ab'cd" | grep "'c"   behaves as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>`</kbd> character (often called a "backquote") is interpreted specially by the shell, *even when surrounded by quotes*.

Specifically, `` `cmd args` `` means "execute the command `cmd args` and replace the backquoted string with the output from that command." If it is surrounded by quotes -- `` "`cmd args`" `` -- the replaced string will not undergo word-splitting or pathname-expansion. (That's usually what you want, so quoted backquotes are common.)

That syntax has been deprecated for a long time, but it is still accepted. New code should use `$(cmd args)` instead. As above, you usually want to avoid word-splitting and pathname-expanding the replaced text, so you'll normally see `"$(cmd args)"`.

In short, if you want to put a literal backquote into an argument string, you should either use single quotes:

```
lsof | grep '/file/path`s/'
```

or <kbd>\</kbd>-escape the backquote:

```
lsof | grep "/file/path\`s/"
```